# Renaming file by using Node Package Version

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, node-modules

I'm trying to a file by Node CLI and using package version.

Example:
package.json version is: 1.0.2
I want to rename a file(zip or txt or simply a folder) in my package and use that string as name, would be fantastic if I can join that string to one other such us: code_1.0.2v.zip or code_v1.0.2.zip.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it's possible. Check out the dupe.

Comment: It wasn't what I was searching but helped to get into a solution. I wanted to do it all by CLI.

Thank you anyway